# How can I make this 2 strings matching algorithm more efficient?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, matching

So I am working on this exercise on code wars and my code does what it is supposed to do, but it needs to be more efficient and I don't know what else I can do. Below are the exercise and code I wrote.

Complete the function scramble(str1, str2) that returns true if a portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2, otherwise returns false.

Notes:

Only lower case letters will be used (a-z). No punctuation or digits will be included.
Performance needs to be considered

```
Input strings s1 and s2 are null terminated.
```

Examples

```
scramble('rkqodlw', 'world') ==> True
scramble('cedewaraaossoqqyt', 'codewars') ==> True
scramble('katas', 'steak') ==> False
```

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
    #initiate variables
    i,j,count =0,0,0
   #sorting our 2 strings
    s1, s2="".join(sorted(s1)),"".join(sorted(s2))
    #for loop to go over each character in the str we want to match, s2
    for j in range(len(s2)):
        
        #while loop to go over s1 to match characters to s2 char
        i=0
        while i<len(s1):
            #when 2 chars match, count increases by 1, i increases to exit while loop
            #s1 sliced for increasing efficiency in the next loop
            if s1[i]==s2[j]:
                count+=1
                x=i 
                i=len(s1)
                s1=s1[x+1:]
            
            #if character larger in s1, no need to go through the whole string
            #therefore, exits while loop and slices
            elif s1[i]>s2[j]:
                x=i 
                i=len(s1)
                s1=s1[x+1:]
            
            #increases iterator
            else: i+=1
    
    #return statement, if count equals length of s2 then it must be true
    if len(s2)==count: return True
    else: return False
```

Side question: is the time complexity for this code O(n^2)?

Comment: You should post this on code review. SO focuses on code/programs which are not yet working while code review focuses on code optimization.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use a hashmap and compare the frequency of letters in s1 to s2? Basically, the question is "can i construct s2 using letters from s1?". You can do that if all the letters in s2 are in s1, right? So can you create a frequency map of letters for s2 and compare to frequency map of s1?

Comment: And there are counters which you can apply on strings to count how often a character appears in a string. It might be a lot more efficient for this case. Have a look at collections.counter

Comment: @JeremyFisher Better yet, you just need to make a pass through s1 to get counts, then a pass through s2 to decrement them.  If you find a character in s2 that is not in s1, or get a count below 0, then the answer is no.  Else it is yes.

Comment: @btilly yes I think that would work as well. more space efficient for sure and clever.

Answer (score 0):

So here you are sorting both strings which gives *O(n log n + m log m)* complexity for *n* and *m* being sizes of `s1` and `s2`. Then you are running two nested loops to check for characters from `s2` to exist in `s1` and then rewriting `s1` if the character in question does exist. This is actually super inefficient, and it indeed gives you *O(nm)* complexity for that part with quite a big constant on top (since you are rewriting a string over and over).

Instead you can just count occurrences of each character in each string to see if you have enough characters to compose `s2` from `s1`. That would give you linear time plus the size of an alphabet, which is a small constant (26 in your case since only lower-case alphabetic characters are allowed according to the challenge prompt).

Comment: Since this is a coding challenge you are doing, I will leave the implementation to you :) Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! You helped me reduce my code to just 4 lines!    
`def scramble(s1, s2):
    for char in s2: 
        if s1.count(char)<s2.count(char):return False
    return True` However, the time complexity of `.count` is O(n) which still makes it inefficient. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sure! There are two ways to improve it:
1. Easiest but still quite inefficient: why looping through all chars in s2 (may be big) if you can just loop through 'a' to 'z' (always 26)? It will give (26 * (len(s1)+len(s2))) iterations
2. Less easy, but of optimal efficiency: create a dict from char to the number of occurrences procedurally: initialize all as 0, then loop through the string once, incrementing proper cell at each iteration. Do that for both strings. Finally, loop through the alphabet and check the values are aligned correctly.That's just (26 + len(s1)+len(s2)) iterations!
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the fact that an exception is thrown if you try to find and pop an element from a list which does not exist:

```
def scramble(s1,s2):
    l1 = list(s1)
    for c in s2:
        try:
            i = l1.index(c)
            l1.pop(i)
        except:
            return False
    return True
```